# How to make my custom annotation processor for Room Entities run before Room annotation processor starts?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I made a small [annotation processor](https://github.com/muthuraj57/roomColumnFieldGenerator) which generates Kotlin class for all Room Entities with fields representing Column names. I did this to use the generated class static final field instead of raw string in @ColumnInfo, @ForeignKey parentColumn, childColumn etc.

The problem is, when I use the field from generated class in say, @ColumnInfo like this

```
@Entity(tableName = "DogTable")
data class Dog(

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = DogTableFields.ID) //DogTableFields class is generated from my annotation processor
    val id: String = ""
)
```

I'm getting build error saying

> error: element value must be a constant expression
>       @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = null)

I think Room compiler's annotation processor runs before my processor and that's why the generated field is null.

My question is, how do I make my annotation processor run before Room's processor runs? or is there any other way to make this work?

Edit: This is the [Dog.java file](https://gist.github.com/muthuraj57/c22991a405999acd5da415c8de24239d) which is generated under /app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug from where the error is shown. You can see that, the @ColumnInfo have `null` for `name`.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @kassim Unfortunately, no :(